# How to perform Ternary statement for 3 conditions with one default condition

Tags: javascript, react-native, ternary-operator

Is it possible to perform ternary for 3 conditions but with one default condition ?

Here is my code :

```
<Button
  rounded={true}
  title='Add Address'
  backgroundColor='#2980b9'
  rightIcon={{name: 'arrow-forward'}}
  disabled={this.state.timeSlotItemSelected === null || this.state.quantityItemSelected === null ? true : false}
/>
```

In this, `this.state.timeSlotItemSelected` is default. What I need, is whenever `this.state.timeSlotItemSelected` and `this.state.quantityItemSelected` are null, the result should be `true`, and whenever `this.state.timeSlotItemSelected` and `this.state.deliveryOptionSelected` are null, then it should also be `true`. Otherwise it should be `false`.

How do I perform this for both conditions?

Comment: do you really want check for `null`? what other values do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a simple combination of `&&` and `||`, and no need of the ternary operator at all.

```
this.state.timeSlotItemSelected === null &&
    (this.state.quantityItemSelected === null || this.state.deliveryOptionSelected === null)
```

This will be `true` if `this.state.timeSlotItemSelected` is null, and if either one of `this.state.quantityItemSelected` or `this.state.deliveryOptionSelected` is null, and `false` otherwise.

Truth table:

```
timeSlotItemSelected | quantityItemSelected | deliveryOptionSelected | Result
---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+-------
null                 | null                 | null                   | true
null                 | <not null>           | null                   | true
null                 | null                 | <not null>             | true
null                 | <not null>           | <not null>             | false
<not null>           | <anything>           | <anything>             | false
```

You do not need the ternary operator in this case, because the expression itself will return `true` or `false`: `<Expression> ? true : false` = `<Expression>`.

Answer (score 0):

(this.state.timeSlotItemSelected === null && this.state.quantityItemSelected === null) || ( this.state.deliveryOptionSelected === null && this.state.timeSlotItemSelected === null) ? true : false

Answer (score 0):

This is some Boolean algebra (I will probably use the wrong words, I learned math in german, so edits or comments are appreciated):

Let's start with your verbal conditions translated into JavaScript (I deleted `this.state` for better readability):

`(timeSlotItemSelected === null && quantityItemSelected === null) || (timeSlotItemSelected === null && deliveryOptionSelected === null)`

We can factor out `timeSlotItemSelected`, so it looks like this:

`timeSlotItemSelected === null && (quantityItemSelected === null || deliveryOptionSelected === null)`

Now you can use it in an if-clause or a ternary operator.

**Concerning your question for a "default condition":**

There is literally no way to have a default when working with boolean, they are either true or false.

This means:
If an if-clause or a ternary operator have a boolean as input (which they have in JavaScript and most other languages), they cannot have a third case for a default, because a boolean can only be true or false.

A variable with the type boolean can have a default value (e.g. false in Java), but not in JavaScript.

Comment: I wonder whether by "default condition", they mean that one condition applies to both test cases. So for `D = default`, we have `D ∧ A => X ; D ∧ B => Y ; else => Z`, where somehow the default case is factored out as; something like `D ∧ (A => X ; B => Y) ; else => Z`. In Lisp/Scheme, you could have `(cond-default D (A X ...) (B Y ...) (else Z ...))`.

Comment: Thanks for the response and glad that it worked perfectly @Daniel

Comment: ya your right @BillyBrown, I mentioned default in the sense, that first condition applies for the both cases !